# asp.net apply same style to textboxes within div

Tags: html, asp.net, textbox

I have 3 div's with over 20 textboxes in each div.
Based on certain rules, each div is enabled or disabled.

I use the following code via VB to disable or enable ALL of the fields in each div, and works great: `div_full1_DETAILS.Attributes.Add("Disabled", "")   div_full1_DETAILS.Attributes.Remove("Disabled")`

Now when I enable the div, I would like to apply a style to each box within the div, and I would like to do it all one hit, just like the code above.

So I would like to apply something like this:

```
div_full1_DETAILS.Attributes.Remove("Disabled")` 
div_full1_DETAILS.Style.Add("border-bottom", "thin dotted #AD9F9F")
```

So the last line of code I would like to apply the style to all the textboxes within the div div_full1_DETAILS

Can this be done ?

UPDATE:

Following comments below and some search on the web regarding child style, etc, I have done as follows, but clearly something is wrong:

CSS

```
 .div_details_dotted * {border-bottom: thin dotted #AD9F9F}
  .div_details_dotted_WHITE * {border-bottom: thin dotted white}
```

VB PAGE
' SET ALL 3 DIVS TO WHITE DOTTED BORDER-BOTTOM

```
div_1_DETAILS.Attributes.Add("class", "div_details_dotted_WHITE")
        div_2.Attributes.Add("class", "div_details_dotted_WHITE")
        div_3.Attributes.Add("class", "div_details_dotted_WHITE")

if username='frank' then
' enable all textboxes in div 1 and put a dotted dark line below...
div_1_DETAILS.Attributes.Remove("Disabled")
            div_1_DETAILS.Attributes.Add("class", "div_details_dotted")
end if
```

However this doesn't work, clearly I've done something wrong.
Each DIV has a dark line around it which it has now dissapears (so the CSS is not being appliedonly to child textboxes but also to div.
Also the `div_1_DETAILS.Attributes.Add("class", "div_details_dotted")` doesn't do anything.

Any ideas how to proceed ??
thanks

Comment: Are you adverse to doing this with a CSS class rather than inline styles, eg. `div_full1_DETAILS.Attributes.Add("class", "dotted-underline");`, then in your stylesheet use the selector `.dotted-underline > input` to style its children?

Comment: using CSS class is fine too, but how do I apply to its children the .dotted-underline? How would I apply, in just one line, the class dotted-underline to all the textboxes inside the div ?

Comment: You don't need to apply the style to all the children with C# - that would be done by the CSS selector `.dotted-underline > input`. You can then just apply the class to the parent (`div_full1_DETAILS`) and still get the desired effect.

Comment: thanks for your input. I have done some search on the web regarding your parent/child logic, and I have made some changes to no avail, see my update on oiginal message.

Comment: Your style is being applied to all children of your div, because you used the universal selector (*). I presume you're concerned with `<input>` elements when you only want the child textboxes styled, which is why I suggested using the more specific `> input` rather than `*`. If you change that, are only the expected elements now affected?

Comment: fantastic! changing to .div_details_dotted > input  {border-bottom: thin dotted #AD9F9F} did the trick.  Thanks. However the master div border also is dissapearing, I assume affected by the code, but I don't know how to get it back. I was under the impression this code would only affect the textboxes inside the div, not the div itself. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm, the style shouldn't be affecting the main div itself - see a [demo of the selector](http://jsfiddle.net/p2hpz5p2/). I can try to help you work through this if you want. Also, can I post a summary of what we worked out as an answer? That way you can mark the question as successfully solved.

Comment: I apologize for my inexperience. I've checked the demo but I can't understand how that can work within my page. Your demo has only two div, so you are applying a general CSS to all divs which is the same. My page has several divs, each one of them has different settings, so I can't use it as per your demo. I'd love to post all the code but it's is huge, so I cannot. I know that will make things easier.

Comment: The demo was really only meant to show how the selector `.div_details_dotted > input` should not be overriding the border of the main div element. Since your full code is lengthy, could you post just a sample of the output HTML, which demonstrates the problem you're facing with styling?